# Gamepad/joystick turbo mode software

Tags: windows, gaming

I'm looking for a program which can be used to enable turbo/autofire mode on a USB game pad, preferably something which at least decently imitates the rate/duration of input events found on actual turbo controllers.

For so simple a function, this seems rarer than a gold-plated unicorn, according to the Google searching I've done.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda workaround but you can use [AntiMicro](https://github.com/AntiMicro/antimicro/releases).
Simply remap desired button on controller to left mouse button and enable turbo.
Then in advanced setting you can change rate up to 50 / sec.

Answer (score 0):

Xpadder can configure your controller to turbo any key, adjustable rate.  I believe reWASD can also do this but the turbo option costs extra.
here is a comparative review

https://www.saashub.com/compare-xpadder-vs-rewasd

Comment: Xpadder also costs $9.99 right now, reWASD is $7 only for turbo($25 for full features).  reWASD lets you try it for 7 days atleast (click "try' instead of 'buy')